# need help in using "routing data" in asp.net 4 (without MVC)

Tags: asp.net

I am newbie to asp.net 4. Pardon me if this question is dumb.

I have a web application tat was running in server with asp.net 3.5 and we migrated the server that to asp.net 4.
Now I need to use the query string in url without question mark.

What I need is to transform the url from `"www.website.com?user_name=test_usr"` to `"www.website.com/test_usr"` and read the test_usr into a variable(querystring or routing data)

I do not want to change the architecture of my application to MVC pattern. 
Could someone please guide me on, if this is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use routing with webforms in .NET 4.

Scott Guthrie has a good overview on the subject located here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

There is a walkthrough on the MSDN site as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551(v=vs.100).aspx

**Here are the steps as I understand them:**

1. Create a **RegisterRoutes()** method in your global.asax.  This should include calls to `routes.MapPageRoute()`
2. Call `RegisterRoutes()` from **Application_Start()**
3. Use `Page.GetRouteUrl()` from pages to form links from within ASP.NET page logic